# Problems converting a UNIX_TIMESTAMP from a SQL query into a Date in java

Tags: java, mysql, date

I have a MySQL query made in this way:

```
SELECT AVG(REALPOWER) AS REALPOWER,
  `OBJECTID`,
  UNIX_TIMESTAMP(LASTUPDATE)/(30*60) AS LASTUPDATE
FROM POWER
GROUP BY UNIX_TIMESTAMP(LASTUPDATE)/(30*60),
  OBJECTID
```

To get my rows grouped by 30 minutes intervals.
Then in Java i want to convert `LASTUPDATE` to a Date.

The problem is i cannot understand how to dwell with `LASTUPDATE`, which has values like these: 
823945.7650000000, 823945.7705555550, 823945.7761111110

Even multiplying them to 1000 to get millis gives me no real value to get a date...

```
double last = Double.parseDouble(rs.getString("LASTUPDATE"));
Date date = new Date((long) last*1000L);
```

Answer (score 0):

A `Date` object in Java is just a point in time.  Using the 7 and earlier API, if you want to actually *see* a formatted date, then you will have to use something like `SimpleDateFormat`.  Here is an example:

```
double last = Double.parseDouble(rs.getString("LASTUPDATE"));
Date date = new Date((long) last*1000L);
SimpleDateFormat sdf = SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS", Locale.ENGLISH);
String dateFormatted = sdf.format(date);
System.out.println(dateFormatted);
```

Comment: I know this, maybe my question was bad written. The problem is that the values which comes out from `UNIX_TIMESTAMP(LASTUPDATE)/(30*60)` does not look like a real timestamp

Comment: @besmart A UNIX timestamp is simply the number of seconds since the epoch (Jan 1st 1970), if you want the sort of timestamp you have in mind, you will have to construct it in Java.  Also, you can look into using the Java 8 date API which makes things easier.

Answer (score 0):

Use `floor()` to convert the double value into an integer type.  Something like:

```
floor(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(LASTUPDATE)/(30*60)) AS LASTUPDATE
```